# R: epidemic diffusion model using two-dimensional non-linear least squares (nls)

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, model, nls

I'm trying to implement an epidemic diffusion model in R. The formula for the diffusion is delta_y=(a+b * y) * (N-y). y describes the current users in period t, N describes the number of potential users, delta_y describes the new users in t and a as well as b are parameters to be estimated. Note that y is the cumulative sum of all previous delta_y. For a single observation (with delta_y and y as vectors) the model simply works with:

```
model1 <- nls(delta_y ~ (a+b * y) * (N-y))
```

Now the problem is that I have a set of observations of this type and I want to estimate the same parameters a and b for all of them. I was trying to use the same formula from above but now delta_y and y are two-dimensional arrays instead of vectors. I receive the error in "qr.qty(QR, resid) : 
  'qr' and 'y' must have the same number of rows"

Details about the data: y as well as delta_y are two-dimensional arrays with 16 columns and 20103 rows. The arrays are created as following:

```
y=matrix(c(data$nearby_1998,data$nearby_1999, data$nearby_2000, ..., data$nearby_2013),nrow=20103)
invCum <- function (data) {result=matrix(nrow=nrow(data), ncol=ncol(data)); result[,1]=data[,1]; for (i in 2:ncol(data)) {result[,i] <- data[,i]-data[,i-1]}; return(result)}
delta_y <- invCum(y)
```

invCum is a function that returns the new users in t given the cumulated users in t (practically an inverse cumsum function).

str(y) delivers "int [1:20103, 1:16] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...".
str(delta_y) also delivers "int [1:20103, 1:16] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...".
Note that not all entries are 0, just many of the first entries.

The columns of the data each have 20103 entries. The model above worked for a single row of the data.

Comment: The asteristiks were just not displayed somehow, I edited the text so that they're visible. I constructed the array like y =matrix(c(data$1998,data$1999,data$2000,...,data$2013),nrow=2). Each column of the data has 20103 rows.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant y=matrix(c(data$1998,data$1999,data$2000,...,data$2013),nrow=20103)

Comment: Ok well you're right, my original column names are nearby_1998, nearby_1999 etc. I just wanted to give an example of how I created the arrays...

Comment: Okay I edited a description of how I created the arrays. I also don't think our comments lead somewhere useful at the moment since I have perfectly working two-dimensional arrays but the problem is that the nls function doesn't seem to accept those.

Comment: I agree with @BondedDust that you need to improve your question. However, have a look at `library(nlme); ?nlsList`.

Comment: Please excuse me, I'm new to this board. I originally left away some infos not to overcomplicate things but I did my best now to make it a bit clearer. If you need even more information, please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the Rhelp archives for that error and finding that a [similar situation was solved by Duncan Murdoch by converting the matrices to "long"-form using as.vector()](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20qr.qty%28QR%2C%20resid%29%20nls#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20qr.qty%28QR%2C%20resid%29%20nls%20page:1%20mid:wfk4blfrdp7fzyer%20state:results) and reviewing the material on nls and nlsList in Pinheiro and Bates, I'm posting the results of some experiments that may be congruent with your data situation. If I understand correctly you have 16 different "runs" of observations of `delta_y` and `y` and your hope was to model them with the same non-linear model. What's not clear yet is whether you expect them all: (A) to have the same parameters or instead (B) expect coefficients to vary with merely the same form. Let's take the (A) case first, which is what the `as.vector()`-solution provided by Duncan Murdoch nine years ago would deliver.

```
newdf <- data.frame( d_y <- as.vector(delta_y), 
                     y = as.vector(y), 
                     grp=rep(letters[1:16], each=20103) )
N=   _____  # you need to add this; not sure if it's a constant or vector
            # if it varies across groups need to use the rep()-strategy to add to newdf
model1 <- nls( d_y ~ (a+b * y) * (N-y)  , data=newdf, start=list(a=0, b=1))
```

If on the other hand you want separate coefficients:

```
 library(nlme)
 model1 <- nlsList(delta_y ~ (a+b * y) * (N-y) | grp, data=newdf, start=c(a=0, b=1) )
```

Here is some testing: First on a single group (the example in ?nls):

```
DNase1 <- subset(DNase, Run == 1) 
> fm2DNase1 <- nls(density ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - log(conc))/scal)),
+                  data = DNase1,
+                  start = list(xmid = 0, scal = 1) )
> summary(fm2DNase1)
==================
Formula: density ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - log(conc))/scal))

Parameters:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
xmid -0.02883    0.30785  -0.094    0.927
scal  0.45640    0.27143   1.681    0.115

Residual standard error: 0.3158 on 14 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 14 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.631e-06
```

Now done on all groups of that dataset without regard to group-ID:

```
> fm2DNase <- nls(density ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - log(conc))/scal)),
+                  data = DNase,
+                  start = list(xmid = 0, scal = 1) )
> summary(fm2DNase)
==========
Formula: density ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - log(conc))/scal))

Parameters:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
xmid -0.14816    0.09780  -1.515    0.132    
scal  0.46736    0.08691   5.377 2.41e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3291 on 174 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 13 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.341e-06
```

And finally on each group separately with the equation form remaining the only constant:

```
> fm2DNase <- nlsList(density ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - log(conc))/scal))|Run,
+                  data = DNase,
+                  start = list(xmid = 0, scal = 1) )
> summary(fm2DNase)
Call:
  Model: density ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - log(conc))/scal)) | Run 
   Data: DNase 

Coefficients:
   xmid 
      Estimate Std. Error     t value  Pr(>|t|)
10 -0.23467586  0.3527077 -0.66535499 0.4749505
11 -0.18717815  0.3522418 -0.53139112 0.5746396
9  -0.14742434  0.3459987 -0.42608348 0.6521089
1  -0.02882911  0.3403312 -0.08470898 0.9267180
4  -0.01243939  0.3351487 -0.03711604 0.9691708
8  -0.09549007  0.3408348 -0.28016525 0.7741478
5  -0.09216741  0.3367420 -0.27370331 0.7800695
7  -0.25657193  0.3613815 -0.70997535 0.4750054
6  -0.25052019  0.3564816 -0.70275765 0.5051072
2  -0.11218699  0.3245483 -0.34567120 0.7763199
3  -0.23007674  0.3433663 -0.67006203 0.5933597
   scal 
    Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)
10 0.4904888  0.3148254 1.557971 0.1076081
11 0.4892928  0.3138277 1.559113 0.1139307
9  0.4723505  0.3075025 1.536087 0.1189793
1  0.4564003  0.3000630 1.521015 0.1148339
4  0.4423467  0.2946883 1.501066 0.1338825
8  0.4582587  0.3018498 1.518168 0.1352101
5  0.4473772  0.2980249 1.501140 0.1407799
7  0.5142468  0.3234251 1.590003 0.1224310
6  0.5007426  0.3185856 1.571768 0.1483103
2  0.4161636  0.2878193 1.445920 0.2457047
3  0.4654567  0.3062277 1.519969 0.2355130

Residual standard error: 0.3491304 on 154 degrees of freedom
```

Comment: Many thanks, seems like the as.vector()-solution above perfectly worked!